# Awkwardness Between Scenes (What happened to my symbol?)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame, timeline, scene

Say we have a flash file, and all the code and objects on the file are described below:

**Scene One:**

only one symbol with the instance name "char" is on the stage

*Code for Scene One:*

```
import flash.events.Event;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function update(e:Event){
    trace(char);
}

play();
```

**Scene Two:**

only one symbol with the instance name "char" is on the stage

*Code for Scene Two:*

```
stop();
```

If you try this out yourself, you will find that the Flash traces  the object char to be "null" for a split moment, and then traces it properly once it has discovered the symbol on the second scene. Does anyone know why this is, since there is a symbol with the instance name "char" on both consecutive scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any specific documentation related to this other than that which is provided by Adobe for the [Event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html) class, but I believe what you are experiencing is related to the differences between the events `Event.ENTER_FRAME` and `Event.EXIT_FRAME` and how the Flash runtime initlializes objects for use.

I ran a test using your code with `Event.ENTER_FRAME`, and experienced the same results you encountered; however, when I used the `Event.EXIT_FRAME` event, the display object did NOT trace as null at all.

Then I took it a step further and set up my timeline exactly as yours; however, changed the event code in Scene 1, Frame 1 to be:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
stage.addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME,update);

function update(e:Event){
    if( e.type == Event.ENTER_FRAME ) {
        trace("ENTER FRAME: " + currentScene.name);
    }
    else if( e.type == Event.EXIT_FRAME ) {
        trace("EXIT FRAME: " + currentScene.name);
    }
    trace(char);
}

play();
```

And when executed noticed something interesting:

```
EXIT FRAME: Scene 1
[object MovieClip]
ENTER FRAME: Scene 2
null
EXIT FRAME: Scene 2
[object MovieClip]
ENTER FRAME: Scene 2
[object MovieClip]
EXIT FRAME: Scene 2
[object MovieClip]
...
```

1. The `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event was *never* called on Scene 1. Probably because that event had already occurred prior to the code on Scene 1, Frame 1 being executed.
2. The `null` reference was actually in relation to the `char` instance not yet initialized on Scene 2. Once the playhead was exiting the frame, probably when the instance was able to be referenced, it read as a MovieClip.

These behaviors are [probably] the reason why so many people recommend using a document class to add objects to the stage as necessary, attaching listeners to the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` to know when they were added, so that you can handle functionality at the proper point in time that they are actually added to the stage; instead of waiting for the object to be able to be referenced via the timeline. My best guess is that if the ENTER_FRAME event had fired on Scene 1, it too probably would have traced `null` for `char`, just like it traced `null` on Scene 2. It may be `null` because the display object on the stage isn't yet initialized and so the code reference to that object isn't yet initialized either.

I wish I had more time to afford to investigating this for you, but this is the best test and explanation I could come up with to describe the behavior you are experiencing.

Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome! I refined a couple of my statements a few moments ago to clarify what happened with the ENTER_FRAME event on Scene 1, Frame 1.